# Executing vlookup until there is no error

Tags: excel, vlookup, vba

I want for a vlookup to run. If it fails, I want to increment the lookup value by 1, then run the vlookup again. I want to continue this process until the vlookup is successful.

How would I go about this?

I tried using some loops and error handling, but I'm new to macros, so I haven't gotten anything to work yet.

Comment: Do you have some sample data? It's likely there's a much better way to do this

Comment: As well as the data, please provide the code.

Comment: The column of lookup values is of dates in chronological order, with random dates missing. (I was using the increment lookup value by 1 to simplify the question).

Comment: In the VBA code use `application.match` instead of `worksheetfunction.vlookup`. It is faster and has additional properties. Pass the value returned into a variant and use `iserror` to determine success. Once you have succeeded, use the variant as the row number in `application.index` to return the result.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps.

```
dim findThis as long, maxThis as long, var as variant, result as variant

with worksheets("MyWorksheet")
    maxThis = application.max(.columns("A"))
    for findThis = (Date - 100) to maxThis step 1
        var = application.match(findthis, .columns("A"), 0)
        if not iserror(var) then exit for
    next findthis

    if findthis <= maxthis then
        result = application.index(.columns("Z"), var)
        'alternate
        result = .Cells(var, "Z").value

        debug.print result
    end if

end with
```

I've added `Step 1` where it would normally not be shown (it is the default) so you can see where you would change the increment if you wanted to look week-by-week.